# Protect my video-Save as enabeled

Tags: wordpress, html, video, youtube

I am selling my lessons over my website using woocommerce. I want to protect my video lessons the maximum I can.

First, I tried to use youtube. I have unlisted my videos, embed them to my website but there is a  youtube logo that popups at the right bottom corner of the video and allows the user to access the video on youtube thus he will able to download it easily.

Second, I thought about saving my videos directly on my website and disable the right click save as feature. But couldn't find anyway. I have found a plugin that disable the right click in all the website and it is frustrating.
I want the user to eb able to click right click -> save as without being able to download it. Check below link, I want exactly something like this.
http://formation.bloginfluent.fr/vivre-de-son-blog

Note that I am a newbie so I need easy direct solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to protect your video content is using vimeo pro (I am not affiliated anyway to them I just did lots of research on this). The example you gave also use vimeo. Make sure you copyright your videos because anything on the web can be copied by someone with the right knowledge and tools, even if you disable right click.